# My pontiac g5 2009 problems with it starting randomly

Tags: starting, pontiac, g5

My pontiac g5 2009 runs great for a couple weeks then all of sudden won't start just clicks...then couple days later fires right up and will run great again for a short time..have changed the terminals they were bad and had alot of carosion on them ran great for almost a month went to start it did nothing and I can't even get the keys out of the ignition

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the battery load and reserve tested? This sounds like a battery with an internal short which comes and goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a voltmeter to measure from the battery negative post to a good ground point on the engine (alternator bracket or case.) It should read zero volts during the starter click. Any reading tells you there is a bad ground connection somewhere. Bad grounds can be affected by weather. Also, during click-time, measure volts between battery positive and good-ground. It should not drop below 11 volts. Low voltage could be starter or battery, so measure the positive volts when you turn on the headlights. It should not drop more than one-half volt.

Comment: Thanks for input..definately seems like battery or wiring..or starter lol

Answer (score 0):

Check the cables between battery and starter as well as battery to body & body to engine - they may be corroded or cracked - causing this type of problem. One vibration can make the connection another break it.

Comment: I will definitely try this it's makes most sense..the battery is in the trunk..and I've seen corrosion on the terminals and wires..changed both and cleaned it off and under the hood where u can jump the battery it was also corroded..